# inspecting mobile web page with chrome devtools results in blank screen

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Debugging a web page running in Chrome on Android (Galaxy S8) via the USB connection in the latest version of the Chrome desktop browser is not working.
Attempting to inspect web pages running on the mobile device results in a
[blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTrlF.png).

When I inspect the blank page that appears in the desktop Chrome browser, I get the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2fpA.png):

```
Uncaught TypeError: InspectorFrontendHost.isUnderTest is not a function
    at Object.Host.isUnderTest (inspector.js:930)
    at Main.Main._gotPreferences (inspector.js:8301)
    at DevToolsAPIImpl.embedderMessageAck (devtools_compatibility.js:33)
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Windows and Linux running Chrome version 65.0.3315.3 (Official Build) dev (64-bit) as well as 65.0.3318.0 canary.

Comment: I'm also getting this issue. FWIW, there's a bug in Chromium for this, track it here: [Mobile remote debugging window is blank](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=802928)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem here. *But I found a solution to my case*.
Before trying the solution I'm gonna present here, tried restarting chrome both desktop and android, restarting phone. Disabling some experimental flags on about://flags cause I was suspecting on some of those. But none of these steps solved.

Then I see the Chrome on Android was v65 and my Desktop was v64.

So:

1. Removed Chrome version 64.0.3282.186-1 with **dpkg -r google-chrome-stable**
2. Downloaded latest version from https://www.google.com/chrome/
3. ..and installed Chrome version 65.0.3325.181-1 with **dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb**

Before:

```
# dpkg -l | grep chrome
ii  google-chrome-stable                        64.0.3282.186-1                                     amd64        The web browser from Google
```

After:

```
# dpkg -l | grep chrome
ii  google-chrome-stable                        65.0.3325.181-1                                     amd64        The web browser from Google
```

Problem solved!
Now it is inspecting android tabs nicely!